# How can I assign web elements to variables while avoiding StaleElementRefference in Selenium Python?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Is there any way to assign elements to variables in Python Selenium while avoiding StaleElementReference Exception?

Say I have the following code structure,

```
class PageObject:
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver
    @property
    def checkbox(self):
        return self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('selector')
...
class TestCases:
    ...
    def test_case(self):    
        page = PageObject(self.driver)
        chk = page.checkbox
        assert(chk.get_attribute("checked") == "false")
        chk.click()
        assert(chk.get_attribute("checked") == "true")
```

This will raise a stale element reference error.

Is there any way to structure my code so that I am able to define an element in the page object class,

and then assign that element to a variable to be used in the test class?

Comment: What error are you getting? Can you share it please?

Comment: if you remove `@property` from your code, does it work?

Comment: Stale Element's are more likely to occur the longer you wait between assigning them to a variable and interacting with them. The best practice with selenium is to find an element as soon as you can before you interact with it

Answer (score 0):

Import this into your page object file:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Then your method

```
@property
def checkbox(self):
    return WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "selector")))
```

Most probably is your element is not present when you are trying to get it.